# Monitoring of the CLFLUSH assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, intel, perf, instructions

I am interested in monitoring the `CLFLUSH` instruction in real-time either system-wide or for a specific process. The platform I am using is on

```
4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux, 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
```

Currently, I am trying to do that using `perf top`/`perf stat` but i am not able to filter on this specific instruction. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered tools like DynamoRIO or Frida? Or Intel PIN?

Comment: Can you check the [Intel Architecture Manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) for Performance counters for Haswell? (or in https://download.01.org/perfmon/index/haswell.html https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-intel-processor-events-reference) If there are some counters incremented for CLFLUSH, you may try to use them as sampling event for perf top. If there is no such hardware count, you may use `perf probe` to add synthetic tracing event on every clflush command in every binary (which is hard for system-wide mode, but easier for smaller single program).

Comment: If (as I suspect) there are no perf counters for `clflush`, this would be a duplicate of [Perf Monitoring for rdtsc dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53390392).